# CLI - restrict terminal to particular area

Tags: linux, command-line

OK, this is a console only system, the images you see are 5 separate screen sessions running omxplayer with a specified window size. As you can see, i have a small windows in the bottom right of my screen. I would like to have htop running in this area, but I can't find a way to accomplish this.

I looked at tmux, but if I understand correctly, i would need to run multiple windows to get a window in the specific area I want it in. the color image will be moving to the bottom right, so htop can span the top row of the 4x4 in the bottom right. (assuming i can get this working!)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I dont know enough about omxplayer to be confident, but I would think that you are using the framebuffer in graphics mode, so you can only use another graphics-oriented program to draw in the bottom right corner. Perhaps you can use imagemagick to convert your text output  (from say `top -n 1|head 20`) to a jpg image, then use omxplayer to display that image (as apparently it can), repeating this in a slow loop.